# WooCommerce API with Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android-studio

This is the first time when I use to work with WooCommerce for a mobile app. I already implement Base URL, Consumer Key, and Consumer Secret. It works well when I check this on postman but there is no data shown in the app after installation and there is no error while installing.

Comment: Please describe the expected behavior. What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: My app does not show data from WooCommerce.

Comment: https://digitaldecoders.in/furniture/wp-json/wc/v1/products when i run API on postman its returning list of all products but when i call this api in app it returns nothing